# Get knockout observablearray length after every update

Tags: knockout.js, observablecollection

so i have this:

```
function appViewModelRecord() {
                var self = this;
                self.returnedDataRecord = ko.observableArray([]);
                self.table_name = ko.observable();
                self.counta = ko.observable();
                self.countb = ko.observable();
                self.diff = ko.observable();
                //
                self.update = function() {
                    $.getJSON("@Url.HttpRouteUrl("ActionApi",new {controller="check",action="recordcount"})", function (data) {
                    $('#heartRecords').fadeTo(400, 1);
                    var mappedData = $.map(data, function (item) {
                        item.diff = item.counta - item.countb;
                        return new recordData(item);
                    });
                    self.returnedDataRecord(mappedData);
                    $('.badge').html(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#heartRecords').fadeTo(400, 0);
                    });
                });
                };
            }
```

and i am using it like this:

```
    var viewModelRecord = new appViewModelRecord();
    updateData();
    window.setInterval(updateData, 30000);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelRecord,document.getElementById('tableRecords'));
    //
    function updateData() {
        viewModelRecord.update();
    }
```

I want in every update to check if the returnedDataRecord arrat has 0 records in order to have a visual indication.

how should i do it?

**UPDATE:**

The view model:

```
    function appViewModelRecord() {
        var self = this;
        self.returnedDataRecord = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.table_name = ko.observable();
        self.counta = ko.observable();
        self.countb = ko.observable();
        self.diff = ko.observable();
        //
        self.update = function() {
            $.getJSON("@Url.HttpRouteUrl("ActionApi",new {controller="check",action="recordcount"})", function (data) {
                $('#heartRecords').fadeTo(400, 1);
                var mappedData = $.map(data, function (item) {
                    item.diff = item.counta - item.countb;
                    return new recordData(item);
                });
                self.returnedDataRecord(mappedData);
                $('.badge').html(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#heartRecords').fadeTo(400, 0);
            });
        };
        self.howMany = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.returnedDataRecord().length;
        });
    }
```

and the update function:

```
function updateData() {
                viewModelRecord.update();
                if (viewModelRecord.howMany() == 0) {
                    $('#noRecords').fadeTo(400, 1);
                } else {
                    $('#noRecords').fadeTo(400, 0);
                }
            }
```

And i have the "record" count. The only problem is that first time it has value = 0.

**UPDATE2:**

Following the upper code , this is my main script:

```
    var viewModel = new appViewModel();
    var viewModelRecord = new appViewModelRecord();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel,document.getElementById('tablePallets'));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelRecord, document.getElementById('tableRecords'));
    window.setInterval(updateData, 30000);
    updateData();
```

The way it is , the first time i dont get the count

Comment: You can use ko.computed() to return length of the collection or to do any checks on it.

Comment: i want to be able to use it in my main script..i could do it?

Comment: Of course, you can use it like ordinary observable.

Comment: Also i thought you want to bind it to html element directly.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets i want to be able to use the legth of the array in the updateData(). How to do it?

Comment: @e4rthdog I suggest your read the [documentation on Knockout computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). It will probably answer many questions for you.

Comment: Can you please show how you push items to the returnedDataRecord?

Comment: @GSerjo I added the update implementation on top of the post

Answer (score 2):

```
<span data-bind="text: count"></span>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>

function MyViewModel() {
 var self = this;
 self.items = ko.observableArray();

 self.count = ko.computed(function() {
     return self.items().length;
 });

 self.addItem = function(){
     self.items.push("item");
 }        
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSG3V/1/)

Comment: this creates the count but on first time it doesnt update. take a look at your modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HSG3V/2/

Comment: Yep, because you've created new ViewModel, but binding was added on another. I've updated your sample http://jsfiddle.net/HSG3V/3/

Comment: op syes..but my situation is still the same, take a look at update2 in my post.

Comment: About "Update2" looks good, but `self.howMany` should be ko.computed

Comment: it is, i just added to the post..Look at update i have also the function that makes the update...

Comment: `self.returnedDataRecord(mappedData);` you've to push or call valueHasMutated. Here's more about arrays http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: but i am passing the mapped array directly. How i should writei it?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.howMany = ko.computed(function () {
                return self.returnedDataRecord().length;
            });
```